# Outlook to Excel VBA to overwrite previous data

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am having some trouble with an excel macro I found on the forum but am unable to fix the problems as I don't really have any idea what I am looking for in order to fix it.

Firstly, I'll explain what I want to do, and then I will paste the VBA I am using in order to do what I want.

1. I want outlook to just copy a specific part of my e-mail into a specific cell. The e-mail part i want will either be "000000" or "100000". I want it to go into B17 and overwrite whatever previous data was in there.

At the moment, I am getting the entire body of the e-mail into the row below what data was copied over before, and I can't seem to change where it goes (at the moment it goes into A1 and decends vertically).

2. Excel wants to open and close each time it receives an e-mail, which is not good for what I am trying to do. I want this work sheet to remain open, but just save after any data is entered into it from outlook.

This sheet will be used as a remote desktop for monitoring, so people can just go up to the screen and say, yes this is the latest information, without going and searching for it (most people who will be using this remote desktop will not be familiar with our server so wont know where to find it, as well as we don't actually want people snooping around our server!).

Anyway, here's the code.:

```
Const xlUp As Long = -4162

Sub ExportToExcel(MyMail As MailItem)
    Dim strID As String, olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strFileName As String

    '~~> Excel Variables
    Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object
    Dim lRow As Long

    strID = MyMail.EntryID
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

    '~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '~~> If not found then create new instance
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Show Excel
    oXLApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Open the relevant file
    Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("\\server-01\company\Rachael\VBAs\Control Panel Visual Layout.xlsm")

    '~~> Set the relevant output sheet. Change as applicable
    Set oXLws = oXLwb.Sheets("Control Panel")

    lRow = oXLws.Range("A" & oXLApp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    '~~> Write to outlook
    With oXLws
        '
        '~~> Code here to output data from email to Excel File
        '~~> For example
        '
        .Range("A" & lRow).Value = olMail.Body
        '
    End With

    '~~> Close and Clean up Excel
    oXLwb.Close (True)
    oXLApp.Quit
    Set oXLws = Nothing
    Set oXLwb = Nothing
    Set oXLApp = Nothing

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Any and all help will be appreciated, I've spent about 2 weeks trying all sorts of things from google, to no avail!

Comment: Can post an example of the email body?

Comment: Hiya, I've actually managed to complete most of the above by using excel formulas (=mid) to pick up specific parts of the e-mail and display it where i want. However the only issue i still have is getting excel to stay open. 

Excel does stay open, however now instead of putting the data into the sheet thats still open, it wants to re-open it all over again ( and prompts me with 'do you want to reopen this file?' or something similar). Is there any way around this? I've changed the bottom part to the below but again, not sure where I'm going wrong:

    oXLApp.save 
(removed close, quit)